# Can I choose which CPUs / Cores to be used by MySQL?

Tags: mysql, performance, mysql-5, windows

I have a Windows VPS (Windows 2008 R2 x64) that runs a couple WordPress blogs and other few ASP.NET things. The VPS runs 2 CPUs (for example).

With ASP.NET, in such situation, I usually set the app pool to use one CPU / Core, and SQL Server to use the other one (just change it in the server properties).

In MySQL, can I tell it which CPU(s) / Core(s) to use?

Comment: possible duplicate http://serverfault.com/questions/49138/limit-cpu-of-single-mysql-process

Comment: Looks interesting, but all is around Linux commands and tools if I get it correctly.

Comment: what about mysql limits, would they help you?  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-resources.html

Comment: Unfortunately not. None of them seems to be related to CPU. I want MySQL to try to use as much RAM as it wants, as much space (in its drive) as it wants, and as much CPU usage as 100% of a specific given CPU, not trying to use the other CPUs.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2777137/programmatically-limit-cpu-usage-by-any-application-on-windows-7 was mentioned one solution:" you can right click the process in the task manager and set the affinity. This will define which cores are allowed to run the process."

Comment: The problem is that this is a very manual solution. Every time the MySQL windows service (or the entire VPS) has to restart (which is not often of course), I have to change it. Just feels wrong.

Comment: However, if there is a way to set a permanent affinity to the MySQL Windows service, that will be a very nice solution.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not the answer you were looking for, but you could use a hypervisor like vmware esxi and use processor affinity to lock the virtual machine to any number of specific cpus.

Comment: This is not on the host. I do not own the host. I own only the VPS. One VPS. I want to do this on the 2 CPUs that are dedicated to this VPS. Actually the fact it is a VPS is not even relevant here (sorry for confusion). I just explained the exact situation.